# Unable to add ppa repository

Tags: apt, updates, wine, ppa

When I am trying `sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:persepolis/ppa`
its showing

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: *****Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.***** .
```

please Solve this!!

Comment: `ubuntu-wine` exists already why are you adding a `ppa` for it?

Answer (score 1):

The `ubuntu-wine` [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) doesn't exist for Bionic so you can expect problems if you try to use it.

Call up **Software and Updates** and click on the "Other Software" tab. Find `ubuntu-wine` in the list and un-check all places it is found.  Then click Close, and enter your password when asked.

Answer (score -2):

You have problems with a Wine repository, apparently the server is down or no longer exists.
It is telling you that it can not connect to the IP
I follow you follow the direct indications from the Wine website.
https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu